# Re-application or Appeal after UK visa refusal

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for UK standard visit visa (6 months) last month and it got refused due to some reasons. It was for tourism/visit purpose.
If I want to apply again, I have to re-apply with all the fee paid again, or is there any appeal/review options also available with updated submission of documents?

Comment: Could you post a picture of the refusal notice with personal details removed? You will get more detailed replies if you do.

Comment: @user16259 It's here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104550/need-to-understand-the-refusal-reasons-of-uk-standard-visit-visa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since April 2015 you can no longer appeal visa application refusals to the tribunal, instead, the correct route is to fill in a new application. There are exceptions from this rule, of course, you can read about them on [gov.uk page dedicated to this matter](https://www.gov.uk/immigration-asylum-tribunal) but this wouldn't be a cheaper or faster option than filling a new and updated application.

But before you do I strongly recommend opening another question with a scan of your Visa refusal letter to avoid submitting a doomed application that will only attract another refusal.

Comment: Thanks. The other question with refusal letter/reasons: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104550/need-to-understand-the-refusal-reasons-of-uk-standard-visit-visa