# Need to understand the refusal reasons of UK standard visit visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for UK standard visit visa (6 months) for tourism, and meeting cousin who lives there.
The reasons of refusal they gave are attached in pictures.

Can you explain points 1 to 5? And it would be great if you can tell what I need to provide for each of them.

For point 1, I did not provide anything. What should I provide?

I assume I will have to re-apply now. Right?

Should I include documents again which I already provided earlier?

[image]
[image]

I have a Schengen Visa, and I applied for UK visit visa from a country (not my national country). But it's not the problem.

Comment: What documents did you provide with the application? And could your cousin not come and visit you, as that likely would be much simpler trip immigration wise. The big question is point 3 - you have a no-work visa for Schengen area, and yet you seem to be employed, can you explain this?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I provided bank statement and a flight reservation (not paid, just the reservation). 
I want to visit UK for exploring and tourism.
I am employed in my national country. Not here in Schengen area. My company has sent me here for some meetings.

Comment: So I take it that you work remotely from within Schengen area with the company back home?

Comment: I hold meetings here on behalf of company back home.

Comment: The crux of the issue is why you are being paid while you are away from your home country. If you are working (as it appears) on a non-employment visa, your credibility about your intention to leave takes a big hit.

Comment: Depending on the detail of what business you are doing while away from home country you may be OK: the UK standard visitor visa allows you to hold meetings for business as long as the actual work will take place in your home country.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I initially thought that this might be a dupe of [our great canonical on 4.2 A + c](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) the circumstances here are not of the usual type.

What most likely sink your application is the point 3 of the refusal. ECO states that your economic situation is not clear for him as you are here on a non-work visa, and yet seems to be gainfully employed. This is a bit of complicated matter and [we also have a separate question with many great answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45092/where-can-i-travel-for-prolonged-periods-of-time-while-legally-working-remotely) for that very issue.

But to get to the point, even if you provide documentation of your current work arrangement (that was missing in your application) you will be fighting an uphill struggle as you could just disappear once landed in the UK and continue working as you do now. The short-term of stay and family only makes this a more significant concern for the ECO. This is something your next application must address and show why you will return from the visit to UK and not disappear in the underground.

If you decide to go through with it, you will likely want some proof of your cousin's existence in the UK, as ECO pointed out you have provided no documentation of such. But generally speaking your application will face an uphill struggle and I would strongly recommend getting professional help from a UK based registered solicitor if you are serious about your travelling plans.

Answer (score 0):

You should address how you are getting income on a non-work visa.

In addition, point 1 in the refusal letter says that you have provided no evidence your cousin is settled in the United Kingdom. I would recommended providing either his passport OR proof his settled status in the United Kingdom. Alternatively, if you have none of this, his passport number including his full name, date of birth, and all of his nationalities, if he holds more than one.